# Consumir dados Json - Webservice Swift 2 - iOS

Tags: json, ios, swift

Preciso Consultar preço na api do buscape (retorna em json) no meu app com swift 2.
Alguem poderia me ajudar fazer isso ou indicar um tutorial de como fazer ?

Como usa api do buscape : [Usando a API do BuscaPé para obter uma lista de produtos usando o Find Product List](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/20042/web-services/usando-a-api-do-buscape-para-obter-uma-lista-de-produtos-usando-o-find-product-list/)

link para teste : http://sandbox.buscape.com.br/service/findProductList/554163674d2f57624d676f3d/BR/?categoryId=77&keyword=samsung

Comment: Qual é a sua duvida? O que você ja tentou fazer ? É no envio de requisições ou no entendimento no artigo ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues minha duvida é como xonsumir os dados... Tipo uma funcao onde passo a url e possa chamala para puxar os dados... Entendeu ?

Comment: Voce ja sabe fazer uma requisição  em swift ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues então , emvamos dizer que não... Como faria?

Comment: Sabe usar Cocoapods ? ja ouviu falar ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues não sei... Ja ouvi ... Mas preferiria sem framework... Mas se você n suber sem ele pode ser com ele...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL e criar um método para baixar os dados de forma assíncrona da seguinte forma:

```
func searchBuscape(query: String) {
    guard
        let escapedSearch = query.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()),
        url = NSURL(string:  "http://sandbox.buscape.com.br/service/findProductList/554163674d2f57624d676f3d/BR/?categoryId=77&keyword=\(escapedSearch)&format=json")
    else { return }
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let data = data where error == nil
        else { return }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            var error: NSError?
            let json = JSON(data: data, options: .AllowFragments, error: &error)
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            print("===json start")
            print(json)
            print("===json end")

            print(json["totalresultsreturned"])  // 16
            print(json["product"][0]["product"]["pricemin"])  // 819.90
            print(json["product"][0]["product"]["pricemax"])  // 1199.00

            // pra voce extrair um array de dicionários do json object você precisa acessar arrayObject property da segunte forma
            if let products = json["product"].arrayObject as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                for product in products {
                    print("productStart=======")
                    print(product)
                    print("productEnd=======")
                }
                let pricesArrayMin = products.map{$0["product"]?["pricemin"]??.doubleValue ?? 0}.sort()
                print("pricesMinStart=======")
                print(pricesArrayMin)
                print(pricesArrayMin.count)    // 16
                print(pricesArrayMin.first!)   // 539.1    (produto mais barato)
                print(pricesArrayMin.last!)    // 2898.99
                print("pricesMinEnd=======")
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Nao esqueça de editar a info.plist a adicionar ao App Transport Security Settings  o dominio do busca-pé ou usar https. Voce também vai precisar de adicionar o file [SwiftyJSON.swift](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/master/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift) ao seu projeto.

Answer (score 5):

Voce pode utilizar a biblioteca [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) para realizar as suas requisições, ela e a mais estável e construída sobe o swift 2.0, outras como [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)  não são tao encorajadas por ainda serem feitas em Objetive-C.

Para adicionar no seu projeto manualmente voce podera ver um destes videos: [Alamofire - Youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=alamofire)

Ou simplesmente seguir o tutorial na documentação do github.

Uma dica para poder gerenciar essas bibliotecas/componentes que voce precisa instalar no seu projeto e o [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org), ele e um gerenciador  de dependências, como o composer do php.

No mesmo site voce encontra um tutorial de instalação para ele, e como incluir as bibliotecas.

Depois que voce adicionar o Alamofire no seu projeto basta fazer uma requisição assim:

```
 let url = "http://sandbox.buscape.com/service/findProductList/564771466d477a4458664d3d/?keyword=samsung"
Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
  .responseJSON {
    response in
      print(response.request) // original URL request
    print(response.response) // URL response
    print(response.data) // server data
    print(response.result) // result of response serialization

    if let JSON = response.result.value {
      print("JSON: \(JSON)")
    }
```

Comment: Irei testar amanha...

Comment: Gabriel estou tendo problemas ao instalar o alamofire manualmente e o me mac da erro ao instalar o cocoapods... Existe algum outro metodo de instalar ?

Comment: @AugustoFurlan que eu saiba ou manualmente ou com cocoapods, que erro você esta tendo na instalação ? tem uma serie de videos para fazer a instalação na resposta.

Comment: deu certo instalar o cocoapods... Porem agora d que não pode encontrar o arqivo plist... Não sei o motivo... O arquivo existe, pois ja o encontrei no finder...