# Como fazer chamada de um web Service em swift2 Xcode 7

Tags: web-service, swift, alamofire

Já tentei 1000 e 1 coisa e ainda não consegui arranjar uma maneira de chamar o meu web service e obter os resultados pretendidos.

Alguém me sabe dizer qual a melhor maneira de fazer a ligação ao meu web-service e de chamar os meus métodos em swift2 com xcode 7?

Comment: seu webservice retorna o que ?

Comment: ele retorna Json

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse post: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109002/consumir-dados-json-webservice-swift-2-ios/109007#109007

Comment: Eu já experimente usar Alamofire no entanto não instalei o cocoapods porque não dizia para o fazer, e não resultou. Amanhã cedo vou experimentar e logo dou um feedback. Mas pelo que vi não é muito fácil proceder á instalação deste componentes. Obrigado

Comment: Pelo contratorio, a instalação é bem simples, mas mesmo assim você pode instalar manualmente, ou se preferir seguir a solução do @Leo Dabus que não necessita de componente

Comment: Sabe qual a biblioteca que ela usa para este JSON `let json = JSON(data: data, options: .AllowFragments, error: &error)`

Comment: Para realizae requisicao nenhuma, apenas para fazer o parse do json que utiliza SwifyJSON

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, segui o teu conselho e fiz com Alamofire no entanto estou com um problema métodos em que tenha que passar parametros obtenho failure no pedido. Coloco no Link o meu código [(http://pasteboard.co/1heVRG8P.png

Comment: A chamada é igual, ja tentou verificar a url ?

Comment: Sim a chamada é em tudo igual apenas com a diferença que na 1º chamada passo parametros e na 2º chamada não, ou seja o problema está na passagem de parametros. Agora não sei é o que estou a fazer de errado para estar a ter erro

Comment: vai no github da library: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire note que existe um terceiro parametro da função que aceita "parametros"

Comment: Infelizmente já tentei e deu este erro  status code: 500, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 1937;
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 03 Feb 2016 12:54:20 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} })

Comment: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500_pt.html

Comment: Pelo que percebo e um erro do webService e que só pode ser resolvido lá? o problema é que tenho esta app a funcionar em objective-c com esse webService e não existe nenhum problema. Só agora que vou passar a app para swift2 é que não estou a conseguir fazer

Comment: @HideCode coloca o seu código que funciona (objective-c), o código que voce tentou e que não funciona (Swift)

Comment: Já consegui, usando o Alamofire, vou postar minha resposta na pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando a biblioteca Alamofire fiz o pedido da seguinte maneira:

```
    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://****.*****.com/*****.svc/rest/GetByID")!
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let parameters = ["ID": "23"]

    do {
        mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
    } catch {
    }

    mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
        .responseJSON{
            response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value{

                let dataSelected = [JSON.valueForKey("Price")!]         //Quando vem apenas um objecto
                print("RESULTADO \(dataSelected)")
            }
    }
```